# Enviar y recibir información

Tags: c#, arduino

Con un programa envío el comando Luz_ON a este programa de abajo MAL HECHO que lo tengo de prueba en la consola de C# para que me devuelva también, pero no funciona.

Código C#:

```
    using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
 
namespace Emulador_Puerto_Serie_Arduino_03
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 
            // alguna inicialización
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM4";
            sp.BaudRate = 115200;
            sp.Open();
 
            // esperamos
            while (true)
            {
                string comando = sp.ReadLine();
 
                if (comando == "Luz_ON")
                {
                    // Enciende el Led.
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
 
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588");
                    Console.WriteLine("\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588");
                    Console.WriteLine("\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588");
 
                    // devuelve el resultado
                    sp.WriteLine("ON - Led encendido.");
                }
 
                // Si le llega el mensaje Luz_OFF.
                if (comando == "Luz_OFF")
                {
                    // Apaga el Led.
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
 
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588");
                    Console.WriteLine("\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588");
                    Console.WriteLine("\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588");
 
                    // devuelve el resultado
                    sp.WriteLine("OFF - Led apagado. ");
                }
            }
 
            // cerramos
            sp.Close();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

En Arduino si funciona, que este es su código de abajo, ya que quiero convertir de ARduino a C#, que haga lo mismo. Recibir datos por el puerto serie y enviarlo automáticamente.

Código Arduino:

```
const byte Led = 13;   // Declaramos la variable pin del Led.
char caracter;
String comando;
 
void setup()
{
  pinMode(Led, OUTPUT);  // Inicializa el pin del LED como salida:
  Serial.begin(115200);     // Puerto serie 115200 baudios.
}
 
void loop()
{
  /*
    Voy leyendo carácter a carácter lo que se recibe por el canal serie
    (mientras llegue algún dato allí), y los voy concatenando uno tras otro
    en una cadena. En la práctica, si usamos el "Serial monitor" el bucle while
    acabará cuando pulsamos Enter. El delay es conveniente para no saturar el
    canal serie y que la concatenación se haga de forma ordenada.
  */
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    caracter = Serial.read();
    comando.concat(caracter);
    delay(10);
  }
 
  /*
    Una vez ya tengo la cadena "acabada", compruebo su valor y hago que
    la placa Arduino reacciones según sea este. Aquí podríamos hacer lo
    que quisiéramos: si el comando es "tal", enciende un Led, si es cual,
    mueve un motor... y así.
  */
 
  // Si le llega el mensaje Luz_ON.
  if (comando.equals("Luz_ON") == true)
  {
    digitalWrite(Led, HIGH); // Enciende el Led 13.
    Serial.write("ON - Led encendido.");    // Envía este mensaje a C++.
  }
 
  // Si le llega el mensaje Luz_ON.
  if (comando.equals("Luz_OFF") == true)
  {
    digitalWrite(Led, LOW); // Apaga el Led 13.
    Serial.write("OFF - Led apagado. ");  // Envía este mensaje a C++.
  }
 
  // Limpiamos la cadena para volver a recibir el siguiente comando.
  comando = "";
}
```

En resumen, intentar que haga lo mismo el programa Arduino en C# si es posible.

Hay gente que quieren hacer pruebas antes de comprar Arduino, se puede emular por decirlo de alguna manera, en C#, que es simplemente enviar y recibir datos por el puerto serie.

Saludos.

Comment: sp.ReadLine() que devuelve ?

Comment: Envías este comando por ejemplo, Luz_ON, automáticamente devuelve este resultado: ON - Led encendido.

Comment: O sea que tienes un programa C# que no funciona. ¿ese es el problema?

Comment: No funciona como debería. A veces funciona, otras no.
El otro programa de C# envío el comando.

        private void button_Activar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] mBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Luz_ON");
            serialPort1.Write(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.Length);
        }

Comment: @Meta entiendo que `sp.ReadLine()` debería retornar "Luz_ON" o "Luz_OFF", te pregunto que cuando NO funciona, que es lo que retorna

Comment: Si desde el otro lado del PC el programa recibe Luz_ON, tiene que retornar "ON - Led encendido.".